# Opening MS Word File

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using `document.Active()` method which is a part of `Microsoft.office.interop.word` namespace. I want to open the file i.e. I want to see the file opened in the Word application. I have set `thetrackRevisions` property true and rest of all the things.

I just want the file to open NOT IN SAVE-AS MODE. Just open so that when I open up a document from DB or from my PC drives I just want it to open.

Here is the code that I am executing:

```
Word.Document tempDoc = app.Documents.Open("E:\\xyz.docx");
// Activate the document so it shows up in front
tempDoc.Activate();

tempDoc.TrackRevisions = true;

foreach (Revision rev in tempDoc.Revisions)
{
   string editedBy = rev.Author;
   //string what = rev.Cells;
}

tempDoc.Close(ref Nothing, ref format, ref Nothing);
```

Any suggestions that come to your mind?

Answer (score 0):

You just want word to open? 
Have you tried

Process.Start('path to word plus filename');